# How to est initial value to the text box with typeahead attribute?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I use typeahead in my angularjs project.

I hava this value to be displayed in textbox with typeahead attribute:

```
  $scope.cities = [{id:1,address:'Berlin'},
                   {id:2,address:'Bonn'},
                   {id:3,address:'London'},
                   {id:4,address:'Miami'}];
```

And here is input text box with typeahead attribute:

```
<input type="text" 
ng-model="city" 
typeahead-input-formatter="inputFormatter($model)"
placeholder="Custom template"  
uib-typeahead="city as city.address for city in cities | filter:$viewValue"
class="form-control"  
typeahead-show-hint="true" 
typeahead-min-length="0"/>
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3IHpnikyMlt4ih5EEqK?p=preview).

How can I set initial value to the text box where cities has for example id=3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to set the default selected value, then you can assign a value to the model in your case it's `$scope.city` (as in HTML you have `<input type="text" ng-model="city" ..`) , like so:

```
$scope.selected = {id:1, address:'Berlin'};
$scope.cities = [{id:1, address:'Berlin'},
                              {id:2,address:'Bonn'},
               {id:3,address:'London'},
               {id:4,address:'Miami'}];
//assign model value
$scope.city =  $scope.cities[3]   
//or do like this - $scope.city =  $scope.selected;
```

Check the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zKkIbyGYetxQejyfBSnG?p=preview

If it's not ordered by id, then you can still find it by **id** (supposing you use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), if not, you can do it with `Array.forEach`):

```
var id_i_need = 42;
var defaultItem = _.find($scope.cities, function(item){
  return item.id == id_i_need;
})[0]
 $scope.city = defaultItem;
```